# Cannot find publish button in power bi server

Tags: powerbi, power-bi-report-server

Is it only me or you guys also cannot find the publish button as it is given in this document - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-create-distribute-apps

Comment: You are mixing Power BI Service and Power BI Report Server.

Comment: isn't power bi service (app.powerbi.com) and power bi report server (app.powerbi.com) the same? i cannot find the publish button in app.powerbi.com

Comment: Powe BI Report Server is on premise (not app.powerbi.com)